# Are legacy Cloud storage permissions required?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

My confusion is why I need to include "Legacy" cloud storage roles. I prefer to avoid things that say "legacy" as it sounds like they'll be deprecated one of these days. 
Am I doing it wrong?

**Here's my case:**

I'm using service account from an appengine project to access files from cloud storage in another project. I'm using the Google Python Client to access the data.

I have assigned roles:

```
Storage Object Creator
Storage Object Viewer
```

But when I try to access files I get an error:

```
<service account> does not have storage.buckets.get access
```

It's only once I add "legacy roles" that it finally has access:

```
Storage legacy bucket writer
Storage legacy bucket reader
```

Here's the code:

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
          source_blob_name,
          destination_file_name))

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
          source_file_name,
          destination_blob_name))
```

Thanks
Rob

Comment: Hi Rob, can you provide the code you're using?

Comment: @FrankNatividad added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

W.r.t to your code, I've added additional comments below:

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, 
destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    """The following .get_bucket() requires storage.buckets.get permission."""
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    """The following doesn't"""
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print('Blob {} downloaded to {}.'.format(
          source_blob_name,
          destination_file_name))
```

**To re-iterate:**

`storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)` requires permission for storage.bucket.get because it's performing a bucket metadata GET request.

`storage_cilent.bucket(bucket_name)` doesn't require this permission because it does not perform a GET request and only creates a bucket object with the name defined by `bucket_name`.

For upload to bypass storage.buckets.get issue:

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks. That seems completely strange to me; in both cases I'm reading from the same bucket, so i don't get why it doesn't work with get_bucket. But thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'd like to better answer the question so you understand it.

`get_bucket` performs a get request on bucket metadata resource. When you don't want to do that only download the file. So instead you'd use `bucket` to create a reference to the bucket with its name, but not perform a GET request on bucket metadata.

Comment: @frank-natividad I have a similar issue, and this doesn't explain it to me. If I give the service account Storage Legacy Bucket Reader and Storage Legacy Bucket Writer roles, our code writes as expected, but if instead I give it the Storage Object Creator role, it fails with `<service account> does not have storage.buckets.get access to <bucket>`. Is there not a non-legacy, non-admin role that can write?

Comment: The Python client library has a way to initialize an instance of a Bucket with and without requesting metadata from GCS. 
w.r.t request metadata from GCS (`storage.get_bucket()`)
If a request for metadata is performed from GCS it requires storage.buckets.get.

w.r.t not requesting metadata from GCS (`storage.bucket()`).
The method only initializes an instance of a bucket and does not request metadata. This allows you to skip needing permission `storage.buckets.get` because no metadata was retrieved.

Comment: @FrankNatividad I'm not looking to bypass the metadata request. I'm asking for a non-legacy, non-admin role that can write. It seems to me like a bug that a service account with Storage Object Creator permission can't write.

Comment: @RobertLauriston my previous comment was focused on the permission error "<> does not have storage.buckets.get". To bypass this and create an object only having Storage Object Creator I've added an upload example.

Comment: This was so confusing, thank you so much!!