# Google cloud get bucket - works with cli but not in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I was asked to preform integration with an external google storage bucket, I had received a credentials json,

And while trying to do 
`gsutil ls gs://bucket_name` (after configuring myself with the creds json) I had received a valid response, as well as when I tried to upload a file into the bucket.

When trying to do it with Python3, it does not work:

While using `google-cloud-storage==1.16.0` (tried also the newer versions), I'm doing:

```
project_id = credentials_dict.get("project_id")
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)

bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

But on the `get_bucket` line, I get:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME?projection=noAcl: USERNAME@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

The external partner which I'm integrating with, saying that the user is set correctly, and to prove it they're showing that I **can** preform the action with `gsutil`.

Can you please assist? Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: What is that `credentials_dict`? For the `from_service_account_info()` call, it has to be the contents of a service account key file formatted. E.g. from the docs for this: ```service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    service_account_info)```

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, if this is the case, I'll put it as an answer, just wanted clarification no what the credentials_dict was first...

Comment: Also, what permissions do you have set for the service account? gsutil uses your user credentials as set by `gcloud init` by default, so your user might have more permissions than your service account.

Comment: you should configure your google could python sdk and initialize it with correct credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that the creds were indeed wrong, but it did worked when I tried to preform on the client `client.bucket(bucket_name)` instead of `client.get_bucket(bucket_name)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#windows) in order to correctly set up the Cloud Storage Client Library for Python. In general, the Cloud Storage Libraries can use [Application default credentials or environment variables for authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#libauth).

Notice that the recommended method to use would be to set up [authentication using environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication) (i.e if you are using Linux: `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/[service-account-credentials].json"` should work) and avoid the use of the `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info()` method altogether:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client(project='project-id-where-the-bucket-is')
bucket_name = "your-bucket"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

should simply work because the authentication is handled by the client library via the environment variable.

Now, if you are interested in explicitly using the service account instead of using `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info()` method you can use the `from_service_account_json()` method directly in the following way:

```
from google.cloud import storage

# Explicitly use service account credentials by specifying the private key
# file.
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
    '/[service-account-credentials].json')
bucket_name = "your-bucket"
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Find all the relevant details as to how to provide credentials to your application [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application).

Comment: What is wrong with `from_service_account_info`? I want to send json creds without the need to save it in a file

Comment: Nothing wrong with that approach! I just wanted to point out the recommended way to handle authentication using the Cloud Storage Client Libraries as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries). Since you can take advantage that the Client Libraries can use Application Default Credentials (read generally from the env variables) to easily authenticate with Google APIs and send requests to those APIs.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: dont use `client.get_bucket` at all.
See for detailed explanation and solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51452170/705745